# Get mongodb wait queue current items size

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is it possible to get the current number of items in the mongodb wait queue?

I see the WaitQueueSize equals to the 5000 (maxPoolSize = 1000) in the MongoClient and curious why I'm getting the MongoWaitQueueFullException. I would like to log the WaitQueue current items and compare it to the application activity, to figure out how we reach the WaitQueue capacity.

Comment: AFAIK, no. It's internal logic in the connection pool. However I vote that the reason is you have too many requests at the same time

Comment: @dododo thanks for the answer. That is the reason, why I would like to track these requests, because from the first glance - there are no places in the application that could do so many requests, even during the high volume/stress test

Comment: you can configure events monitoring to see what happens in the connection pool. See: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/reference/driver_core/events/ and pay attention on `ConnectionPoolCheckedInConnectionEvent`/`ConnectionPoolCheckedOutConnectionEvent` events